# Shrinking Clipart to 1/12 of its normal size

Tags: images

Can anyone recommend a good way to reduce clipart without it getting too blurry?

I'm currently using Photoshop Elements (but am not opposed to using something else) to reduce purchased clipart.  I am making things for my granddaughter's dollhouse, which is 1:12 scale. So something that is 1' in real life is 1" in her dollhouse. When I reduce most stuff it usually isn't very sharp. For example, if I want to print something on fabric to make a doll pillow, the final image isn't always great.  I've been using jpg, png and tiff images - I want to say the tiff images seem better than my other choices.

Is there a better way to reduce images?  I realize that resizing is always going to cause loss of quality, but is any one way better than what I'm currently doing?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Do you know if the the clip art is vector or raster? What format is the clipart in?

Comment: Most of them are jpgs - some are also available in DXF

Comment: I wouldn't try scaling them in raster software like photoshop, you're likely resampling them which will degrade their quality - by reducing the number of pixels. Perhaps try placing them into MS Word or any word processor, resizing there, and then printing.  I could suggest using page layout software or vector software, but not sure how you feel about learning new software that may just be too complex for your needs.

Comment: I'd be ok with trying new software that doesn't reduce the number of pixels.  It might take me a while to figure it out, but it could be worth my time!  I'm getting frustrated with the bad quality....

Comment: Inskcape (which is free) can import jpegs - sometimes DXF too, but you might need to convert them to jpeg first. I haven't had much success.  You can just select a raster image and rescale it by dragging the handles. Doesn't actually resample the image - just makes it smaller.

Comment: Wow, who knew?  Thanks!  I will give that a try!